# angular 6 toggle button with timestamp

Tags: angular6

So I have this toggle button outputs a time stamp, but it's not working exactly how I want it as I want it to time stamp when toggled and time stamp again when "untoggled". Right now I get two time stamps with one toggle. See here:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

interface TimeStamp {
  startTime: Date;
  stopTime: Date;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <h1>Punch it</h1>
    <toggle-button class="toggle-button"
    (click)="handle()"
      (changed)="checked=$event">
    </toggle-button>
    <p>Your are {{checked ? 'PUNCHED IN' : 'PUNCHED OUT'}}.</p>

    <button (click)="handle()">Stamp</button>

    <p>start : {{timeStamp.startTime|date:'HH:mm:ss.SSS'}}</p>
    <p>Stop: {{timeStamp.stopTime|date:'HH:mm:ss.SSS'}}</p>
  `,


  styles: [ `
    h1 {
      color: #DB5B33;
      font-weight: 300;
      text-align: center;
    }

    .toggle-button {
      margin: 0 auto;
    } 
  `]
})
export class PunchComponent  {
  checked: boolean;
  timeStamp: TimeStamp 

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  handle() {
    if (!this.timeStamp) {
      this.timeStamp = {
        startTime: new Date(),
        stopTime: undefined
      }
    } else {
      this.timeStamp.stopTime = new Date()
    }

  }
}
```

What I would like to have is this: 
1. toggle:
TIMESTAMP A 
2. toggle:
TIMESTAMP B

ideally:

3. toggle:
   TIMESTAMP C
4. toggle:
   TIMESTAMP D

and so on.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you post the result you obtain toggling the button?

Comment: or can you put a console.log into handle() method to see if it is called twice?

Comment: PunchComponent.html:7 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'startTime' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (PunchComponent.html:12)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11087)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10463)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11351)
    at Object.debugCheckAndUpdateView [as checkAndUpdateView] (core.js:11029)
    at 
...

Comment: for this you need to instantiate startTime object into PunchComponent's constructor or ngOnInit

Comment: for your main problem about the two timestamp please make a stackblitz.com working example, I can't reproduce your problem